# Find the N highest cost vertices that has a path to S, where S is a vertex in an undirected Graph G

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, tree, graph-algorithm

I would like to know, what would be the most efficient way (w.r.t., Space and Time) to solve the following problem:

> Given an undirected Graph G = (V, E), a positive number N and a vertex S in V. Assume that every vertex in V has a cost value. Find the N highest cost vertices that is connected to S.

For example:

```
G = (V, E)
V = {v1, v2, v3, v4},
E = {(v1, v2),
     (v1, v3),
     (v2, v4),
     (v3, v4)}
v1 cost = 1
v2 cost = 2
v3 cost = 3
v4 cost = 4

N = 2, S = v1

result: {v3, v4}
```

Comment: How the result is `v2, v4`? I think the result should be `v3, v4`.

Comment: One clarification is needed: you are asking `Find the N highest cost vertices that has a path to S`. And, there is no path cost attached to it. That means, while finding whether a path exist from a vertex `v` to `S`, we only need to consider the connectivity and do not need to consider any path cost?

Comment: Yeah the result should be v3, v3. I've changed it, thanks!
The cost that I mean is not about the path, but about the value of vertex. Then means that in the connected graph of S what are the N vertices that has the highest costs.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, I attempted to make an answer of this question.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solved easily by the graph traversal algorithm (e.g., **BFS** or **DFS**). To find the vertices connected to `S`, we can run either **BFS** or **DFS** starting from `S`. As the space and time complexity of **BFS** and **DFS** is same (i.e., time complexity: `O(V+E)`, space complexity: `O(E)`), here I am going to show the pseudocode using **DFS**:

```
Parameter Definition:
  * G -> Graph
  * S -> Starting node
  * N -> Number of connected (highest cost) vertices to find
  * Cost -> Array of size V, contains the vertex cost value

procedure DFS-traversal(G,S,N,Cost):
  let St be a stack
  let Q be a min-priority-queue contains <cost, vertex-id>
  let discovered is an array (of size V) to mark already visited vertices

  St.push(S)
  
  // Comment: if you do not want to consider the case "S is connected to S"
  // then, you can consider commenting the following line
  Q.push(make-pair(S, Cost[S]))

  label S as discovered

  while St is not empty
    v = St.pop()
    for all edges from v to w in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
      if w is not labeled as discovered:
         label w as discovered
         St.push(w)
         Q.push(make-pair(w, Cost[w]))
         if Q.size() == N + 1:
           Q.pop()

  let ret is a N sized array
  while Q is not empty:
    ret.append(Q.top().second)
    Q.pop()
```

Let's first describe the process first. Here, I run the iterative version of **DFS** to traverse the graph starting from `S`. During the traversal, I use a `priority-queue` to keep the `N` highest cost vertices that is reachable from `S`. Instead of the `priority-queue`, we can use a simple array (or even we can reuse the `discovered` array) to keep the record of the reachable vertices with cost.

#### Analysis of space-complexity:

- To store the graph: `O(E)`
- Priority-queue: `O(N)`
- Stack: `O(V)`
- For labeling discovered: `O(V)`

So, as `O(E)` is the dominating term here, we can consider `O(E)` as the overall space complexity.

#### Analysis of time-complexity:

- DFS-traversal: `O(V+E)`
- To track `N` highest cost vertices:

  - By maintaining priority-queue: `O(V*logN)`
  - Or alternatively using array: `O(V*logV)`

The overall time-complexity would be: `O(V*logN + E)` or `O(V*logV + E)`

Comment: this is a hell of an answer

Comment: Thanks, that looks great!